# Drupal 7 private messaging module

Tags: drupal

I might be missing something here but here is my problem:

I want private messages to be visible only to the participants of a specific conversation. For example, if userA sends a message to userB, I want only the 2 of them to be able to see the conversation. In the permissions of the module, there is a permission called: "read all private messages". Here is my problem:

- When this permission is disabled for my authenticated users, the /user/me/messages path returns an error: "You are not authorized to access this page."
- When this permission is enabled for the authenticated users, the /user/me/messages path returns the proper page but users can also see other users' private messages.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Which module are/were you using? [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg)?

Answer (score 0):

"Read all private messages" is for the admin to be able to snoop on other user's messages. You obviously don't want to give that to users. For users, there should be the "Read private messages" permission (given by default) that will only give them access to their own messages.

If that doesn't do what you want to (e.g. if it only provides one side of the conversation), I'm afraid the module doesn't support what you want natively, i.e. you would need to change the code to implement what you want.

Comment: when i disable the read all private messages then the message menu item did not show even for the user viewing his own messages

Comment: @user3101493: A different menu item is supposed to show, possibly only if there are messages. The `user/%/messages` thing is indeed only meant for the "all messages" way of access.